# WPF DataGrid CheckBoxColumn binding mode = TwoWay error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here is my code

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="30" IsReadOnly="False">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path = chk, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have an exception 
Binding type TwoWay OneWayToSource or can not work with read-only property "chk" type "System.Data.DataRowView".

When I do mode = OneWay, all good.But i need to change the target object and source object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property binded to ComboBox "chk" does not have "set" implemented and so as it has only get it is considered as readonly . Implement set and call INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify change in the property.

Comment: You need clarity on your error or on INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: Can you edit your code and add the chk property code which is in your C#?? It will be easy to understand when I tell you the exact place where you are going wrong.

Comment: you must say that I do not use mvvm.I get the data from the dataset.

Comment: If you are using Bindings, hten there should be a property in C# to put in Xaml. What happens is when there is any change in the C# property, the same change is reflected on UI as it is binded to a WPF control.  Please go through the following link.  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/